# stopping an animation in non-root animation nodes

Tags: animation, qml

I want to stop an animation something like this:

```js
Behavior on x {
    NumberAnimation {
        id: animationElement
         duration: 100
    }
}
    ...
if (something)
{
    animationElement.stop()
}
```

but this code gives me error, that stop() cannot be used on non-root animation nodes.
It's possibly stopping animation from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me :

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle
{
    color: "grey"
    width:  800
    height: 800

    NumberAnimation on width { id: animationElementw ;  from: 800; to: 500; duration: 8500 }
    NumberAnimation on height { id: animationElementH ;  from: 800; to: 500; duration: 8500 }

    MouseArea
    {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked:
      {
          animationElementw.stop()
          animationElementH.stop()
      }
    }

    Text
    {
        id: name
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Click me to stop shrinking animation!!!"
        color: "white"
        font.pixelSize: 25
    }
}
```